# How to generate Json file after execution finish

Tags: json, automation, protractor, cucumberjs

I'm working with cucumber and protractor and to generate reports i'm using

`cucumber-html-reporter` I already add the configuration to generate the report

```
var options = {
        theme: 'bootstrap',
        jsonFile: 'reporter/cucumber_report.json',
        output: 'reporter/cucumber_report.html',
        reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
        launchReport: true,
};
defineSupportCode(function({ After }) {
    After((scenario)=> {
      reporter.generate(options);
     });
    });
```

but i'm not generate the json file with this code, I search in google and the code to generate the json file should be add into the `cucumberOpts` in the `conf.js` but i'm not sure what's the code should be into `cucumberOpts` to generate the json file and the convert into report.

I hope you can help me guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people that still have this problem, in my case the problem was that I was using cucumber v1 instead cucumber v2. For this case I should use `registerHandler` instead `After` this is the complete example:

```
defineSupportCode(function({registerHandler}) {
  registerHandler('AfterFeatures', function (features) {
        reporter.generate(options);
  });
});
```

Hope this help u guys.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://github.com/wswebcreation/protractor-cucumber-typescript-boilerplate/blob/1.1.0/e2e-tests/config/helpers/reporter.ts) can help you, it's for Typescript but the code is almost the same. You can export the file in an `After`-hook. The link is for CucumberJS 1, if you look into the master branch you can also find the CucumberJS 2 solution

The advantage of this in comparison to generating the JSON file with the `format` option is that you can modify the JSON before saving

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the reponse I already generate the Json file but now I have this error `Unable to parse cucumberjs output into json: 'reporter/cucumber_report.json' SyntaxError: reporter/cucumber_report.json: Unexpected end of JSON input` i'm not sure what is mean, do you had this error before?

Comment: Can you share the code that generates the JSON and the JSON output itself?